# Distribution of IOS app through website

Tags: ios, app-store

Initially the plan was for me to publish the IOS app on app store. However, as apple need 1 to 2 week time to approve by app, it would be impossible for the app to be available for my company event on Monday. So my boss suggested me to put the IPA file on company website for customer to download the app.

**Question 1 : Is it possible to distribute IOS app through a download link in a website to download the IPA file so that any customer will be able to install it on their device?**

I have tested and tried installing the IPA file using itune, diawi,ifunbox but it did not install successfully.However it works when i use xcode to install the IPA file on the apple device

**Question 2:
From what i read from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3927786, does it mean that my code has to include some form of device id to allow certain device to be able to install?**

**Question 3: 
Is there any way for me to allow customer to download my company IOS app without app store. This is because my apple developer account is still pending creation and the company event is on monday?**

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying is possible then it would be a lot of competitors to Apple's AppStore , the only possible way is to collect the UUIDs for any device that can download the app , add them in the development provision profile and upload the build to say diawi , so it can be download but for devices included only which it should be up to 100 devices